# Power consumption on StartUpdatingLocation and Significant-Change Location in swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, location, battery

So I want to update location with distancefilter of at least 1609 meters (1 mile) or more frequently. I can manually set the distancefilter in StartUpdatingLocationf and for Signifcant-Change location it updates ~500 meters (more frequent). But, I want to chose the most power-friendly option. Which one would that be?

Comment: Power consumption is dictated by the accuracy of the location you request.  If you use "best" location accuracy then the GPS hardware is powered up and you will use more power. The distance filter just controls how far you move before the location update is delivered to your delegate, but internally iOS is getting more frequent location updates. You could experiment with different location accuracy settings and measure energy impact on the device, but I suspect that using significant location updates will be easier and give you a low energy consumption solution

Comment: @Paulw11 "To start the significant-change location service, call the startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges() method of your location manager. With this service, the location manager ignores the values in its distanceFilter and desiredAccuracy properties, so you don't need to configure them." ~ Apple Docs for Signifcant-Change Location. So, I can't really change the accuracy. Does this change anything in terms of your answer, like being more definitive?

Comment: No.  The issue is that turning on the GPS hardware consumes far more power than receiving the location updates in the background.  If you specify a low accuracy for your location updates (to avoid turning on the gps) then you are basically re-inventing significant location change. Using significant location change has been optimised by Apple to reduce energy use, so it is the best option for the use case you describe.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you